# Check Time between two numbers in php

Tags: php, numbers

I am having issues with the following code:

```
if (Date("D") == "Sat" or Date("D") == "Sun") {
    echo("No School");
}
else {
    if (Date("g") >= 2 && Date("i") >= 10 && Date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("No School");
    }

    elseif(Date("g") == 8 && Date("i") <= 15 && Date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Homeroom");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 8 && Date("i") >= 15 && Date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 1");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 9 && Date("i") <= 30 && Date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 1");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 9 && Date("i") >= 35 && Date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 2");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 10 && Date("i") <= 50 && Date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 2");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 10 && Date("i") >= 50 && Date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Lunch");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 11 && Date("i") <= 35 && Date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Lunch");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 11 && Date("i") >= 35 && Date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 3");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 12 && Date("i") <= 50 && Date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("Period 3");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 12 && Date("i") >= 55 && Date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("Period 4");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 1 && Date("i") >= 0 && Date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("Period 4");
    }
    elseif(Date("g") == 2 && Date("i") <= 10 && Date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("Period 4");
    }
}

?>
```

I want to check what the current time is and then echo which period you would be in. I tried changing my system time to an earlier time yet it still says that there is no school. I'm not sure if it has to do with the code or if the php checks your timezone based on something other than that of your computer time.

Comment: this uses the current server time (the server the script is running on), not your desktops time.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your logic will output nothing at all weekdays before 8am, or between 9:31am and 9:34am, or between 12:51pm and 12:54pm

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your logic and *eliminate early*:

```
$now = time();  // change this to test other times

if (in_array(date('N', $now), array(6, 7))) {
    // Sat or Sun
} else if ($now < strtotime('8:15', $now)) {
    // before start
} else if ($now < strtotime('9:30', $now)) {
    // first period
} else if ($now < strtotime('10:30', $now)) {
    // second period
} ... {
    ...
} else if ($now < strtotime('14:30', $now)) {  // use real time, not AM/PM ;-P
    ...
} else {
    // after school
}
```

If the time is before the start, it's out, otherwise, if it's before the second period, it's the first period, otherwise, if it's before the third period, it's the second period and so on. That also helps you cover all cases in between and a final `else` covers everything after.

Comment: you do not need so many strtotimes. save the currect time in format, for example, "hh:mm" and compare to that string :) `date('N', $now)` also does not need `$now` ))

Comment: @Cheery 1) Maybe it technically works by comparing strings `"11:30"` to `"10:30"`, but it feels dirty to me to rely on lexical comparison when you're really looking for numerical comparison. 2) `$now` is in every call so you can set `$now` to a different value to test other days/times.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code works fine. You have to specify your time zone.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');

if (date("D") == "Sat" or date("D") == "Sun") {
    echo("No School");
}
else {
    if (date("g") >= 2 && date("i") >= 10 && date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("No School");
    }

    elseif(date("g") == 8 && date("i") <= 15 && date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Homeroom");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 8 && date("i") >= 15 && date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 1");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 9 && date("i") <= 30 && date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 1");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 9 && date("i") >= 35 && date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 2");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 10 && date("i") <= 50 && date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 2");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 10 && date("i") >= 50 && date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Lunch");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 11 && date("i") <= 35 && date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Lunch");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 11 && date("i") >= 35 && date("A") == "AM"){
        echo("Period 3");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 12 && date("i") <= 50 && date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("Period 3");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 12 && date("i") >= 55 && date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("Period 4");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 1 && date("i") >= 0 && date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("Period 4");
    }
    elseif(date("g") == 2 && date("i") <= 10 && date("A") == "PM"){
        echo("Period 4");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("Too early to school");
    }
}
?>
```